# Design pattern for separation of concerns

Tags: java, design-patterns, separation-of-concerns

I've am looking for a design pattern to provide separation of concerns and keep the my operations segregated.

In my application I'm getting say 1000 requests, which needs to perform one of 3 given operations, namely, Op1, Op2, Op3.

Each operation have two or three sub-tasks.

```
Op1 -> Add, Remove
Op2 -> Add, Remove
Op3 -> Add, Remove, Update
```

[image]

I've these 1000 requests beforehand, so it is not like they are coming one by one.

Also these requests themselves mentions which specific Task & Sub-task needs to be performed.

Before assigning request to any operation, there is a validation that needs to be done on these requests.

Then based on the requested operation, Op1/Op2/Op3 & corresponding sub-task should be performed.

Initially I thought to use Command Design Pattern but since I've multi-level of tasks, I'm don't think it is the best approach.

Comment: If each task can be made up of subtasks then that sounds like a [composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), especially if subtasks can have subtasks. But honestly you haven't given us enough information. I tend to find this approach of "i'm going to think of the perfect design before i write anything" to be ineffective. You will learn things while you're implementing it which throw off your plan anyway. The most productive thing to do is just start writing something. When you run into some *specific* problem, that's when you can think about which patterns might solve it.

Comment: I guess strategy pattern can be useful here. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm

Comment: Also for operation you can use chain of reponsibility pattern

Answer (score 1):

You need a strategy pattern here to do seperation of operations.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm

```
  Context operation1 = new Context(new OperationAdd(), new OperationRemove());      
  operation1.validate(object, Type.ADD)

  operation2 = new Context(new OperationAdd(), new OperationRemove());      
  operation2.validate(object, Type.REMOVE)

  operation3 = new Context(new OperationAdd(), new OperationRemove(), new OperationUpdate());       
  operation3.validate(object, Type.ADD);
```

Comment: Sorry its not clear, but if I want to execute add on Context1, how will I do that?

Comment: You can use chain of responsibility and pass paramter to validate method a TYPE